# Javascript regular expression for search from starting letter?

Tags: javascript

I want add search functionality. I need to search any document by starting letter.

Suppose, we have to some document like-

```
Apple Industry
Samsung Industry
Xioami Industry
Ahua Industry
Sumatech Industry
```

When user search a then it should give the result which one start with a like-

```
Ahua Industry
Apple Industry
```

You can see the result show alphabetically

I already create a regex like this-

```
{ Industry: { '$regex': 'a', '$options': 'i' } }
```

But it show all the content that contain `a`.

Like-

It show every content because all the content contain `a`.

How can I solve that. Can anyone help me.

Comment: the regex you want is `^A`, or use [`.startsWith('A')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

Comment: Then if user search `ap`?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the `startWith` modifier to your regex. I'm not sure how this object gets converted to the regex, but here you go:

```
{ Industry: { '$regex': '^a.*', '$options': 'i' } }
```

```js
function matchText(query) {

  const text = ['Apple Industry',
  'Samsung Industry',
  'Xioami Industry',
  'Ahua Industry',
  'Sumatech Industry'
  ];

 const regex = new RegExp(`^${query}.*`, 'i');

 text.forEach((item) => console.log(item.match(regex))); 
}

matchText('a');
matchText('ap');
```

Comment: Can you say, I want to put variable instead of hard codded. Like `/^a.*/i` Here instead hard coded a, I want to put variable that value I get from another place like frontend. I want to say that,  `const search = "a", then /^search.*/i, something like this.

Comment: is it possible?

Comment: @Kate Sure, you can use the `RegExp` class to dynamically create regex based on some query. Let me add one example in the above snippet

Comment: @Kate check the code snippet now. I think this is what you're looking for?

Comment: nice answer, I was looking to search for a string from start and not as a sub string